# Get paperclip to crop the image without validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, paperclip

Hello fellow stackoverflow members.

I have been following this [guide](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images) to enable users to have their own avatar.

But i have bumped in to a litle problem.
When the user is cropping the image the model tries to validate all my validations.
My user model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "100x100>", :large => "500x500>" }, :processors => [:cropper]

  attr_accessor :password, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  attr_accessible :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password
```

And when the user runs the crop updating script the `user` model tries to validate the password. But because i have no password field on the cropping page it can't validate it.

Here is the updating of the crop:

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated user."
  end
```

How can i bypass this in a easy and clean way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `#save` and pass it `false` to disable validations for that one database update.

Change your controller code to this:

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
@user.attributes = params[:user]
if @user.save(false)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated user."
end
```

This would cause you problems if you were relying on Paperclip to do image validation.  It might cover up some problems with badly formatted image files, but it's possibly worth the trade off.

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional validation:

```
validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :password
validates_presence_of :password, :if => :password
```

Comment: this is not really a good idea i think, this will caused problem in the original form where password is really required

Comment: Not really. Because the if in this case checks for null. The only way for the password to be null is for it to be left off the form or the value is set to null in code. Either way it would be a programming and not a user validation. I agree it's a quick and dirty, but it's food for thought for the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the technique used by [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/v2.1.3/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/password.rb), try validating the password only when it's new record, the password has changed, or the crypted password (the column where you store the hashed/crypted password) is blank.

```
class User
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :require_password?
  validates_presence_of :password, :if => :require_password?

  def password=(pass)
    return if pass.blank?

    # Encrypt password, etc
    # ...

    @password_changed = true
  end


  private
    def require_password?
      new_record? || @password_changed || crypted_password.blank?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to @htanata, but using [ActiveRecord:Dirty](http://caboo.se/doc/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html):

```
class User
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => 'self.password_changed?'
  validates_presence_of :password, :if => 'self.password_changed?'
end
```

Comment: Or `:if => :password_changed?` for brevity.